# configuration update on a fast path packet processing

Tags: c++, multithreading, configuration, updates

We have got an application which processes incoming packets with a thread pool. Each thread has got a configuration which is being used while packet processing.

We are currently using mutex to lock before a check for configuration has changed or not.

This makes threads to spend too much time to lock the mutex to check if there is a configuration update. We are wondering if there could be faster alternative you guys can suggest.
Implementation is with C++

Regards.

Comment: Is each thread just processing a single packet, or a stream of packets? Do you need to check for changes for every packet? Wouldn't it be easier if each thread got a static copy of the configuration when it starts the processing? Is that feasible?

Comment: Use a reader-writer lock instead of a mutex if there is a pattern of a lot of read-only access to the config, but relatively infrequent write access (to update the config)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg each thread is processing a packet and check if there is a configuration change, It is not feasible because configuration is changing at random times

Comment: So each thread just process a single packet? What does it do with the packet? Is the processing a long-running process or just a quick one and then done on to the next packet? If it's a quick one then I don't really see the need to check for changes while doing the processing, and instead you do it between the packets. It would really help if you could give us more information about what you really are doing, it will make it easier for us to help find a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to address this would be through [atomics via `std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic). Following is a simplified solution to a simplified version of your problem. In the following, your problem has been simplified to a single processor thread (the multiple case is the same, in principle). The first version of the solution "leaks" on config changes. For rare enough config changes (which, at least from my experience, is a very common case), this might be acceptable. Otherwise, I'll describe in the end two ways to address it.

Say you start with the following configuration class:

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>

constexpr int init_config_val = 3;

struct config{
    int m_val = init_config_val;
};
```

The configuration has a single value field, `m_val`.

Now let's set types for an atomic pointer to a configuration, and a list of configurations:

```
using config_atomic_ptr_t = std::atomic<config *>;
using config_list_t = std::list<config>;
```

The thread process takes a pointer to an atomic configuration pointer. When it needs to access the configuration, it calls [`std::atomic::load`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/load).

```
void process(config_atomic_ptr_t *conf) {
    while(true) {
        const config *current_config = conf->load();
        ...
    }
}
```

(Note that the above shows the thread checking the configuration at each iteration; in some types of applications, it might be enough to check it "often enough".)

When a different thread wants to set the configuration, it calls the following function:

```
void modify_config(config_list_t &configs, config_atomic_ptr_t &current_config, config conf) {
    configs.push_back(conf);
    current_config.store(&*configs.rbegin());
}
```

The function takes a reference to the list of configurations, a reference to an atomic configuration pointer, and a new configuration object. It pushes the configuration object to the end of the list, then uses [`std::atomic::store`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/store) to set the pointer to the end element in the list.

This is how `main` can set up things:

```
int main() {
    config_list_t configs;
    configs.push_back(config{});    
    config_atomic_ptr_t current_config{&*configs.rbegin()};

    std::thread processor(process, &current_config);
    config new_conf{init_config_val + 1};
    modify_config(configs, current_config, new_conf);
    processor.join();
}
```

As stated before, each configuration change pushes a new configuration object to the list, and hence this program effectively has unbounded memory requirements.

At least from my experience, many applications need to support config changes in principle, but they're expected to be rare. If this is so, the above solution might be acceptable. (In fact, you can simplify things by removing the list, and just allocating new configurations on the heap.)

If not, there are at least two alternatives.

The first alternative involves fixing the above as follows:

- In `config`, add another field describing the configuration version - say, an integer.
- Send the `process` thread also a pointer to an `std::atomic<int>`.
- Periodically (say once every 1000 iterations), the thread would check the version of the config it's using, and set the `std::atomic<int>` to reflect it.
- A cleanup thread (possibly the main thread) would also periodically check the value of the `std::atomic<int>`, and clean up the list accordingly.

The second alternative is just passing your thread function a pointer to something like [`boost::lockfree::queue`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/lockfree/reference.html#header.boost.lockfree.queue_hpp). At each iteration (or once every number of iterations), the thread could check the queue for a new configuration, and then use it.

---

**Full Example**

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>

constexpr int init_config_val = 3;

struct config{
    int m_val = init_config_val;
};

using config_atomic_ptr_t = std::atomic<config *>;
using config_list_t = std::list<config>;

void process(config_atomic_ptr_t *conf) {
    while(true) {
        const config *current_config = conf->load();
        if(current_config->m_val != init_config_val)
            break;
    }
}

void modify_config(config_list_t &configs, config_atomic_ptr_t &current_config, config conf) {
    configs.push_back(conf);
    current_config.store(&*configs.rbegin());
}

int main() {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    config_list_t configs;
    configs.push_back(config{});    
    config_atomic_ptr_t current_config{&*configs.rbegin()};

    std::thread processor(process, &current_config);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    config new_conf{init_config_val + 1};
    modify_config(configs, current_config, new_conf);
    processor.join();
}
```